# GIT Noob - How do I prevent unintended merges?

Tags: git

I am new to GIT and am curious about the appropriate workflow (it is only my 2nd SCM with my 1st being Clearcase).  Let's assume that there are 2 GIT branches: `Master` & `Foobar`.

John edits a file, `hello.txt`, where his changes must ONLY be on the `Foobar` branch.  John checks out the `Foobar` branch, makes his change, and commits it.

Jane now needs to make a change to `hello.txt` that needs to be in BOTH the `Master` & `Foobar` branches.  She checks out the `Foobar` branch, makes her change and commits it.  She then checks out the `Master` branch and pulls in the file from the `Foobar` branch.  However, she has now inappropriately merged John's changes into `Master`.

How does one avoid this situation?  In the Clearcase world, it would be John's responsibility to create a merge arrow to ensure that his changes are not merged towards `Master`.  Is there something similar in GIT?  Or is there a better workflow for this?

Comment: You could make the change in `master` and then merge master to `foobar` (if you are fine with other changes of master propagating to foobar)

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  There are some changes that need to be specific to Master...some changes that need to be specific to Foobar...and some changes that need to be everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

if you are on branch A and want the changes in a commit on branch B, what you want is to **cherry pick** that those changes. See [Google: git cherry pick](http://www.google.com/search?&q=git+cherry+pick)

if you do `git pull B`, you've just merged B into A; which is what you want to avoid. but luckily undoing a merge is easier than performing one. if it hasn't been pushed any where, all you've got to do is reset the head of A to the commit before the merge.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Cherry-picking looks promising since it appears that I can pick out certain commits.  But at the same time, this seems inefficient because from this point forward, both John and Jane must always cherry pick in order to ensure that John's original changes don't make it into Master.  Correct?

Comment: `git cherry-pick` is the answer. The real problem is that you should define a workflow. Common approach: (1) master for current release andbug fixes, (2) feature branches for new work, (3) next for merging feature branches into plus eventual merge to master for new release.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a merge arrow in git.

It sounds like Foobar is branch where changes are made that shouldn't be going to master.  If that's the case then Jane should've started her work in master and merged it down into Foobar.

Comment: Don't we run into the same problem?  If Jane started in Master and merged it down into Foobar, how would she keep from merging other changes that should not be in Foobar?

Comment: @user1175330 there's really no way. Git doesn't really have a concept of "keep this file only in this branch".